# How can I create a web based administration interface

Tags: html, frameworks, administration

I'm planning to create a simple web based interface that stores administration input in json format
(for use later by an applicaiton running on the same host)

example json output is here: http://www.json.org/example.html
The content would be user contacts (email, name, phone number, photo etc..)

There would need to be a conf file per logged in user.
and an administrator user for viewing all config files in his group.

I'm wondering what technology is best to create this framework.

I could do it via servlets etc.. however, there may be something simpler..

Thanks to all for your replies in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building an admin interface is really no different from building a web app. Use whatever frameworks are available in your language of choice.